# Using SCP to transfer files from Windows to Mac

Tags: unix, sftp, file-transfer, scp

I am trying to write a script that, executing from a mac, will download 4 files from a windows machine to my current directory. I tried downloading those files using scp, but whenever I try connecting to the host, I receive a "Operation timed out - lost connection" message. After doing some research, I found out that I need an ssh daemon tool on the windows machine in order to complete the connection. I installed FreeSSHd and tried using scp again, but with no success. I also tried turning off my windows firewall, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know why I am getting the timeouts? What would be steps I needed to follow to be able to use scp from a unix machine (mac) connecting to a windows machine?

P.S.: Would it be possible that I am not using the correct IP address to connect to the host? I ask because I also tried "ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" on the mac and I received a timeout message

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so  what is your question? Is it that how Can you check ur IP or anything else? Please clear your question.

Comment: What is Windows machine's IP and Mac Machine's IP?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I believe using Samba to access your files is a more direct approach

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question and I believe it is more precise now. @arturhoo: Samba wouldnt work because I am not the administrator in the Mac machine

Comment: If you recieve timeout from ping you need to see what is the problem in the conection between win and mac before to start trying the scp copy test

Comment: Hmm, what should be my next step? I turned off my win firewall and tried, but that is not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you P.S. it is pretty clear that your issue lies deeper. Since you can't even ping the Windows machine from the MAC host (and assuming ICMP packets aren't being filtered), I recommend checking the network and connectivity of your hosts (if there is a network admin, he could be of great help), especially:

- that both computers are connected to an internal network or to the internet;
- that there are no other firewalls in the network;
- the window's host IP (`ipconfig` in the command line in the windows host);